# Добавить аналогичную первой строку в GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Есть .fxml файл, в котором описан `GridPane` с одной строкой, в которой находятся два `ComboBox`.

По определенному событию должна создаваться новая строка в `GridPane` с аналогичными `ComboBox`, которые должны добавляться в список для возможности обращения к ним.

Подскажите, пожалуйста реализацию обработчика для данного функционала, т.к. не могу понять как "клонировать" `ComboBox` в новую строку.

Comment: вам нужно клонировать или же новый комбобокс создавать?

Comment: Мне нужно в конечном итоге иметь лист этих комбобоксов, чтобы управлять их содержимым, и при необходимости удалять.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить строку gridPane.add(new ComboBox(), 0, 1); 0-колонка , 1 строка (вторая).

```
  button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        gridPane.add(new ComboBox(), 0, 1);
    });
```

Экземпляр одного объекта в разные строки добавить не получится, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added:

Comment: Эта ошибка возникает из за того, что вы пытаетесь в одну и ту же ячейку записать 2 разных компонента, а не потому, что экземпляр объекта в разные строки добавлять.

Comment: А если, допустим, при каждом нажатии на кнопку, строка добавлялась в конец? Прошу прощения, не очень четко поставил условие.

Comment: то создаешь новую RowContains, добавляешь ее в gridPane. Далее берешь количиство строк - 1 и по этому индексу добавляешь комбобокс.
Вопрос - почему именно gridPane? не проще будет использовать VBox?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov Получается, что RowConstraints добавляется в конец? И если мне нужно будет последнюю строку удалить, то я просто возьму последний элемент из gridPane.getRowConstraints()? Я думал класть в HBox VBox'ы, но мне показалось костылем каким-то.

Comment: 1. RowContains ты добавляешь туда, куда тебе надо, т.е. gridPane.getRowContrains() возвращает Lits<RowContains>. 
2. Нет, надо будет идти по всем элементам, и брать тот, у которого GridPane.rowIndex(Node node) будет последним индексом.
Классы VBox и HBox как раз и предназначены для этого, а класть в gridPane - это как раз и костыль)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov. Благодарю. Последую Вашему совету, буду делать с помощью VBox'ов в HBox'ах